# Android app to silence the phone

Tags: gratis, android, audio

Looking for Android app to **instantly** silence the phone 100% (equivalent of holding volume key down till slider goes to 0).

Requirements:

- On Google Play
- Decent reviews (4+ stars)
- Operates by simply clicking the icon. No sliders, or other GUI elements.
  I'm OK if the app itself has more functionality, but provides a single-click silencing shortcut that can be placed on the launcher
- Compatible with the [Shush!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.publicobject.shush&hl=en) app (or contains same functionality)

Would strongly prefer free (as in beer) but if it's very good, non-free is OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Minimalist Silence Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.omarbs.widget&hl=en) seems to be a good fit.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

It's free, seems to be the most basic (no sliders, extra bloat, features, etc.) and has a 4.4 on Google Play.

From the Google Play Store description

> Minimal Silence Widget its an useful Ringer Mode Toggle widget.
>
> It offers a simple way to switch beetwen ringer sound modes in one touch. It also updates its icon when the ringer mode its toogled elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The Playstore holds a bunch of widgets to turn things on and off. So my suggestion might be "taking a truck to buy a bottle of beer", but it includes solutions for far more (similar and other) tasks in the future:

I use **[Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** for a lot of "simple", but also for more complex jobs. *Tasker* is not only "a", but most likely "the" automation solution on Android. With this app, you combine "conditions" (triggers) with "tasks" (what should be done), and both cover a wide variety of things. Concentrating on your current question, you could create a simple task:

*Audio Settings* → *Silent Mode*, "On"

Then on your homescreen, select to add a shortcut, select "Tasker", select that Task. There you go.

But you could go even further, making that a full-fledged profile. I can think of multiple different triggers proving useful here:

- *Event → Sensor → Shake*, select a pattern (e.g. left-right) and duration (e.g. 2 sec).
- time-based (silence it at night)
- location based (silence it at work; based on GPS, network location, WiFi network near, cells near)
- incoming phone calls from people you want to ignore
- button presses (e.g. long-press on search button)
- battery level

These are just a few examples, a ton of addons offer even more (including voice-control). Chose from the above (or even combine triggers), and assign above created task to it.

[image: Tasker profiles] [image: Tasker task] [image: Tasker categories]
<sup>Selected *Tasker* screenshots: Profiles, a task, categories (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

I have to admit, *Tasker* is not coming "cheap" (about US$ 4 currently). But it's worth every cent; I couldn't do without it anymore. A free 7-day-trial is available [on its homepage](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/); and when you export all its settings on day 6, then uninstall, re-install, and re-import the settings, you get another 7 days (no bad trick – argument from the dev himself). And over on Android.SE, you will find good help on this app (a good starter is the [Tasker tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info), and the [questions using this tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tasker)). Some days I get the feeling almost every second issue we get at Android.SE can be answered with "Use Tasker" :)

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include Tasker on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) instead? Google Play would probably be preferable to download from and it's apparently cheaper there as well.